# How can I get Dreamscene wallpapers to change randomly in Win7?

Tags: windows-7, desktop-customization

Having only recently moved over from Windows XP to Windows 7, I’m a big fan of the ‘Dreamscene’ animated wallpaper. I’m also a big fan of the Win 7 ability to select a group of still wallpaper bitmaps and set it to randomly change wallpapers every ‘X’ minutes/hours.

What I want is the ability to do the same with the dreamscene animated wallpapers, i.e. select a group and they randomly change every ‘X’ minutes.

Beyond that, I’d also like to be able to select a group of stills *and* animated wallpapers and randomly change between them.

Comment: Is dreamscene even officially supported any more? I realise you can install it, as you could with lower end versions of vista, but is there any actual support?

Comment: Not sure there is but I'm hoping there's some (free) third party utility to do what I want.

Answer (score 3):

Dreamscene is not supported, but you can easily get it back, with a utility called [DreamScene for Windows 7](http://www.dreamsceneseven.com/). (which works in Windows 8...)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Dreamscene is no longer supported but the video player VLC does a fine job [as a substitute](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/18167/set-a-video-as-your-desktop-wallpaper-with-vlc/).

The bonus here is that the random changing is built-in: just build a playlist (CTRL+L) and set it on loop and shuffle.